# Sharepoint 2010 - How can I define PROGRAMMATICALLY whether Office Web Apps installed on server?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I am using C# programming language and want to define whether Office Web Apps installed on server in order to hide/show `<SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate Text="Open in browser" />`

My variant is as follows

```
bool b = File.Exists(@"C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\Web Server Extensions\\14\TEMPLATE\\LAYOUTS\\WordViewer.aspx");
```

but I need something else... what is the correct method?

Comment: This question may be better answered in http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ I have posted a few questions there and got a good quality answer.

Comment: Thanks. I ve found solution  [here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/43399/10086)